# How to create a volume group, logical volume and a file system on AIX?

Tags: filesystems, aix

I'm getting some difficulties to create a file system on an AIX server. In Linux the task is easy and takes four commands, but I cannot figure out how to do it in AIX.

On Linux I'd do the following:

```
lvcreate -L 6G -n oracle_rec_sei data_vg
mkfs -t ext3 /dev/data_vg/oracle_rec_sei
mkdir -p /appli/oracle/REC_SEI
mount /dev/data_vg/oracle_rec_sei /appli/oracle/REC_SEI
```

On AIX I am trying with the following commands but in this case there isn't a volume group defined. The commands I've found are giving me errors according to the absence of a volume group.

I'm trying to create a filesystem of 0.25G with this commands:

```
mklv -y lvoractl01HIST -c 1 jfs2 2 --> 2 blocks of 127Mb
crfs -v jfs2 -d /dev/lvoractl01 -m /appli2/oracle/AGEV/oractl01 -a agblksize='4096'
mount /dev/lvoractl01AGEV
```

I obtained numerous errors with the first command (`mklv -y lvoractl01HIST -c 1 jfs2 2`) because it needs the definition of a volume group.

What are the steps to create a volume group, a logical volume and a file system (all of a given size) on an AIX host?

Comment: So your question really is "how do I create a logical volume in AIX that I can later make a file system on?" (guessing from `mklv`), right?

Comment: Yeah, i don't understand exactly the equivalent commands in UNix that i usually use in linux to create filesystem of a desired size.

Comment: I've edited your question to hopefully clarify exactly what you are looking for. If you feel the edit changes the intent of your question, do feel free to [edit] further. (I'm not familiar with AIX myself.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a volume group.

`mkvg`

Create a logical volume in the volume group.

`mklv`

Create a filesystem on that logical volume.

`crfs` or `mkfs`

Couldn't get more consistent naming than AIX commands (pre-around v6).

Obviously, you can use the man pages to get everything you need.  But at their very basic level,

`mkvg -y myvg hdisk5 hdisk6` (create a volume group call myvg which contains the physical volumes hdisk5 and hdisk6).

`mklv myvg 10G` (create a logical volume, with the default name, in the myvg volume group of at least 10GB in size).

`crfs -V jfs2 -d /dev/lv01 -m /my/dir/fs` (create a filesystem called /my/dir/fs mounted on the /dev/lv01 logical volume, of type jfs2).

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt, there's always: 
smitty crfs

I know it's a newbie tip, but in there you can press F6 to get the official command that's run by the IBM tool. Then use that in future.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explain more clearly please?  What is this tool?  How does one install it? Run it? How exactly does this answer the OP's question?